# is Autocad and Adobe software written in C++ or in .NET?

Tags: c++, .net, autocad

My question is if Autocad (Autodesk Autocad 2014) source code mainly written in C++ or in .NET.
The same for Adobe creative suite.

Of course it has some plug in or interface versus many platform, or scripts, etc... but I want to know exactly the main software how it is manufactured.

Please reply only if 100% sure information from an employee.

My cousin keeps saying that Autocad was written in .net.

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to know? If it was .Net, I'd be surprised. AutoCAD does have a .Net API though.

Comment: There's very little commercial (off the shelf) software written in .NET.

Comment: AutoCAD is mostly C++ with some .NET and also LISP for many of the Express Tools commands.

Answer (score 1):

I heard that AutoCad, begining with 2009, has WPF UI wrapper. This is old software, so it is 99.9999% that this is C++. So this is 90% of C++ and 10% of .net))